# VBA: Internet Explorer object does not show correct LocationName

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, ms-word

I am working on a simple Word macro below that opens an IE page and displays its location.
The macro works correctly for Internet Web pages. However, if the Web page is a local file, the shown location is always about:blank.

Why this happens and how can I get the real location?
I tried the trick that enumerates all open windows and it works.

However I am wondering why the direct method below does not work for local pages.

OS: Windows 7 + IE8

```
Option Explicit

Dim oIE

Sub Macro()

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    oIE.navigate "about:blank"

    oIE.Top = 0
    oIE.Left = 0
    oIE.Width = 500
    oIE.Height = 500

    oIE.navigate "C:\test\test.htm"

    oIE.Visible = 2

    Do While (oIE.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    MsgBox oIE.LocationName

    Set oIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my tests the Internet Explorer Object detaches itself once it loads...

By looping through the Shell Windows you can find and Re-Assign the IE object.  Once this is done  I'm able to successfully query for the LocationName

See my test routine below:

```
Sub Macro()
Dim oIE, oShell, objShellWindows, strPath, X

    strPath = "C:\test\test.htm"

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'oIE.navigate "about:blank"
    oIE.Top = 0
    oIE.Left = 0
    oIE.Width = 500
    oIE.Height = 500

    oIE.navigate strPath

    Do While oIE.Busy And oIE.ReadyState < 2
        DoEvents
    Loop

    MsgBox oIE.LocationName & vbCrLf & oIE.LocationURL

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objShellWindows = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    For X = objShellWindows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Set oIE = objShellWindows.Item(X)
        If Not oIE Is Nothing Then
          '  Uncomment below line to troubleshoot
          '  MsgBox oIE.LocationName & vbCrLf & oIE.LocationURL
            If StrComp(oIE.LocationURL, "file:///" & Replace(strPath, Chr(92), "/", 1, -1, 1), 1) = 0 Then
                Do While oIE.Busy And oIE.ReadyState < 2
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                oIE.Visible = 2
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        Set oIE = Nothing
    Next
    Set objShellWindows = Nothing
    If oIE Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could Not Find The IE Window"
    End If

    MsgBox oIE.LocationName & vbCrLf & oIE.LocationURL

    Set oIE = Nothing

End Sub
```