# The called object is disconnected from its clients in Excel VBA - Webscraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I have a project at the company, where i should collect data from an intern website und write them down in excel. Therefore i tried web scraping with excel vba.
My Code looks like this:

```
Sub WebScr()
Dim Internet As InternetExplorer
Set Internet = New InternetExplorer
Internet.Visible = True
Internet.navigate ("intern company link")
Do While Internet.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE:
Loop
MsgBox Internet.LocationName
End Sub
```

When i try the same thing with a different link it works. Is there maybe a problem with the internal server? Can i fix this with Excel VBA or should i try it different?

Thank you very much

Comment: So what does `not work` means? If you browse the said URL in IE manually,, does it load? I won't be surprised if the said URL does not support IE anymore and thus the issue.

Comment: The last part of the code. The MsgBox Internet.LocationName does not work. When i try to access to the link manually everything works. VBA also has no problem opening the URL but it has problems extracting information out of it. With a open link everything works normally. When i try the same thing with the intern URL Adress it pops up an error Automation Error The called object is disconnected from its clients

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432699/vba-internet-explorer-object-does-not-show-correct-locationname)? @RadoslavKaravangelis

Comment: i have tried it now. the msg box pops up and says "could not find the IE Window" . If i comment out the middle section (from Set oShell = Create Object To MsgBoxc "Could Not Find the IE Window End if) it pops up an error: the remote server is non existing or not available.

Comment: IE should no longer be used. However, you can try the following for your problem to try to avoid your error, which often occurs in intranets when using IE with VBA: Do not instantiate IE with `Dim Internet As InternetExplorer` and `Set Internet = New InternetExplorer`. Instead, use `Dim Internet As Object` and `Set Internet = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")` Here you can find more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/ieinternals/default-integrity-level-and-automation

Comment: omg! this is working! thank you a lo @zwenn you made my day!!

Comment: I'm glad to read that :-)